# Drawbacks with using entity framework without using statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, using

There a lot of code blocks like this:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    DbEntities entity = new DbEntities();

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        entity.someOperations...
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        entity.someOperations...
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Detail()
    {
        entity.someOperations...
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Detail()
    {
        entity.someOperations...
        return View();
    }

    .....
```

Should I change the methods like this?:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        using(DbEntities entity = new DbEntities())
        {
            entity.someOperations...
        }

        return View();
    }
    .....
```

What are the problems with not using `using-statement` in EF? OR what is the best way? Also, If we use `using-statement` code blocks are grown.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using` statement approach is the best of the two that you have proposed above. Using this approach, you can be assured that the `ObjectContext` is closed and disposed of after it's use.

Using your other approach, one would assume that the `ObjectContext` could be left unclosed, therefore hogging connections to the database. To see this in action, try creating a sample app with your other approach, then profile it using the [EFProfiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) and watch the number of `ObjectContext`'s opened rise, whilst the number of closures will be notably smaller.

I recently worked on a project that was having database issues under high levels of usage that adopted your second pattern (you can see my question about it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729429/entity-framework-closure-of-object-contexts)). As I didn't have enough time on the project/code base was too large, I didn't have the option to switch to the `using` statement approach. Instead I implemented the following to manually force the disposal of the `ObjectContext` on the `End_Request` in Global.asax (I had an instance of the `DbContext` on a static instance of my `BusinessLayerService`:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BusinessLayerService.Instance.Dispose();
        BusinessLayerService.Instance = null;
    }
```

But if you have the option from the project start: **I would highly recommend using the `using` pattern**

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot. but I wonder, what is the problems about my first example. What problems will be occur in future...

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi No problems, the problem is sometimes you can't be suren if the connection to the database is ever even closed (i.e. the `ObjectContext` is closed). As the `using` statement calls `.Dispose()` on the `ObjectContext`, you can be sure that it's destroyed when using the `using` statement.

Answer (score 5):

There's no big problem in your example above if using **using-statement** but it's very hard to write unit tests for code like that, when dbContext is a local variable.

If you don't follow any design pattern like Repository, Unit of Work, you don't want to write unit test, then wrap all logic in **using statement** is the best choice in this case.

Comment: @phnkha can you give a good reference to Repository, Unit of Work implementation