# How to attach a new DbContext object to an entitty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching

I sometimes get `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

Is there any way to renew a ObjectContext 
for a specific entity?

(one that stayed in my application from previous request (i.e. my caching layer))

Comment: why don't you create a new instance of object context and fetch the entity from DB again?

Comment: Did you manage your dbContext as per-request?

Comment: @daryal is rigth. in your scenerio, ObjectContext disposing have no meaning. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643491/drawbacks-with-using-entity-framework-without-using-statement

Comment: What is exactly your scenario? Are you using EF behind a services layer? If so, you should create a new instance of the context for each request.

Comment: @CuongLe I create an new instance per request, but I also save the result in an enterprise librrary cache, as I mentioned in my question

Comment: @daryal I create an new instance per request, but I also save the result in an enterprise librrary cache, as I mentioned in my question

Comment: @EladBenda instead of renewing context, I would advise to detach the object from context after using it, or before closing the service call, then reattaching it to a new context.

Comment: how do I detach or reattach?